# Vertica error when changing data types

Tags: sql, vertica

I'm trying to convert a column from varchar to bigint using the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE 'table_name' ALTER COLUMN 'colname' SET DATA TYPE BIGINT;
```

But I get the following error:

```
SQL Error [2377] [0A000]: [Vertica][VJDBC](2377) ROLLBACK: Cannot convert column "colname" from "varchar(128)" to type "int"
[Vertica][VJDBC](2377) ROLLBACK: Cannot convert column "colname" from "varchar(128)" to type "int"
com.vertica.util.ServerException: [Vertica][VJDBC](2377) ROLLBACK: Cannot convert column "src_mainuser" from "varchar(128)" to type "int"
```

The column has int values like 37439510 but in varchar format.

Comment: seems like a data issue and you have a non integer in there somewhere.   Try select colname::bigint from tablename (pretty sure thats a valid data conversion syntax for vertica)  if that errors out, you've got a char or two in that column.

Comment: Did that...no errors...

Comment: Might be a Vertica limitation...that error isn't giving much for information, no mention of conflicting data types really.   Contact vendor, the Vertica dev team might have a better answer than what I say next.   Standard work around, create a second table that has the column as big int, and then mass insert all lines from the old table into it.  Drop old table, rename new table.   If you get a better answer from vertica, please share.

Comment: Vertica support won't help...this is a limitation they are aware of.  answer up

Answer (score 2):

Answer is not possible, this won't work by Vertica deifnition:

https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/Tables/ChangingAColumnsDataType.htm

Two methods.

1. Create new table, load new table, drop old, rename new.
2. Create new column in table.  Load column from old.  Alter table to remove old column

Comment: Yes...these are the only ways possible. No direct typecasting available

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your table, try:

`ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN colname_as_int INT DEFAULT colname::INT;`

Then:

`ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN colname_as_int DROP DEFAULT;`

Then:

`ALTER TABLE table_name DROP COLUMN colname;`

And finally:

`ALTER TABLE table_name RENAME COLUMN colname_as_int TO colname;`

Only works, however, if you have no projections on `table_name` with `colname` as an ORDER BY column or a SEGMENTED BY HASH() column; you would have to replace those projections with another superprojection and drop those projections first ....